# "Characteristic" of an ideal?

Tags: nt.number-theory, terminology

Let $K$ be a number field and $I$ be an ideal in the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$.  Let $n$ be the smallest positive integer in $I \cap \mathbb{Z}$.  I'm trying to figure out what to call $n$.

When $I$ is prime $n$ is the characteristic of the residue field.  Is it appropriate to call $n$ the "characteristic of $I$" for general $I$, or is this a horrid abuse of terminology?  Is there something else that's widely accepted?

EDIT: It looks like ``characteristic'' can be defined for any ring, so $n$ is the characteristic of $\mathcal{O}_K/I$.  Perhaps it's not too much of a stretch to call it the characteristic of $I$??

Comment: This is just the norm of the ideal, no?

Comment: @Cam: It's the norm of the ideal pulled back to $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: No, it is not, but it divides the norm.

Comment: (That was a comment to Cam's question)

Comment: "Generator of the integer pullback"?

Comment:  subnorm        ?         

Comment: I certainly wouldn't say "characteristic of $I$".  "Residue characteristic of $I$" would be better. (This is what I, and many others, would say in the case when $I$ is a prime ideal, although using it in the non-prime case is unconventional, and would merit an
explanation the first time you used it in your paper.)

Comment: Ah, yes.  I reluctantly concede that not all ideals are prime.

Also, agreed on "residue characteristic."

Comment: I myself would feel weird calling it residue characteristic, given that I would never say "the characteristic of the ring Z/4Z is 4."  You could certainly call it Ann_Z (O/I), or "the rational annihilator" for long.
 